# GPO installation (office add in)

Tags: deployment, outlook-addin, gpo

I created Outlook add in and installer (using Installshield LE 2013). My msi package has dlls in a separate folder, but this package works fine when I try to install add in local.
I have problem with installation via GPO. I created test security group in AD with one user, and I was trying to set GPO object like [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/01/25/automatic-installation-windows-group-policy/). GPO was succesful applied, but my add in wasn`t install. I have not found any warnings or errors in event viewer or Policy events in group policy results wizard. Maybe someone had similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on MSI logging. Then run the package again. Just to see if the MSI actually actually ran. If the MSI log does not exist, then the MSI never launched. This is a good first step in problem-solving before deciding whether there is a problem in the actual MSI.

There are many ways to enable MSI logging. You can probably find in stack overflow or Microsoft. Here is one link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300. Alternately you can enable in the launch command in msiexec or /v command line.